# Set Partylist value using array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to set the value of the partylist from an array, which formatted from selected contacts. But I got exception indxIds is undefined, tried a lot to figure it out but couldn't do so. Here is in the following what I'm trying to do:

```
//arrIds is the array of guids of selected contacts

var partyList = new Array();

for (var indxIds = 0; indxIds < arrIds.length; indxIds++) {
    partyList[indxIds ] = new Object();
    partyList[indxIds].id = arrIds[indxids]; 
    partyList[indxIds].name = selectedname[indxids].Name; 
    partyList[indxIds].typename= 'contact';         
}

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").setValue(partyList);
```

I need your kind help where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive, so `indxIds` and `indxids` are considered 2 different variables.

You are defining `indxIds` in your `for` loop, but using `indxids` (which is `undefined`) to index your `arrIds` and `selectedname` arrays.

In addition Dynamics CRM lookups require `entityType` and not `typename`

Try:

```
for (var indxIds = 0; indxIds < arrIds.length; indxIds++) {
    partyList[indxIds] = new Object();
    partyList[indxIds].id = arrIds[indxIds]; 
    partyList[indxIds].name = selectedname[indxIds].Name; 
    partyList[indxIds].entityType = 'contact';         
}
```

or even better, you can use an object literal:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrIds.length; i++) {
    partyList[i] = {
        id: arrIds[i], 
        name: selectedname[i].Name,
        entityType: 'contact'        
    };
}
```